# Is it possible to disable screen recording without FLAG_SECURE in Android?

Tags: android, android-security

I need to disable screen recording/capture in my application, but keep the ability to take screenshots. Looked into `FLAG_SECURE`, but it blocks both taking screenshots and capturing/recording video. But I need to **DISABLE SCREEN RECORDING/CAPTURING ONLY.**

Comment: No.  Those are a single permission.  Because they have to be-  take screenshots every .1s and you can throw them together into a video.  You can't block videos unless you also block screenshots